# What's the meaning of "to hold it up against" here?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

[Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/why-did-paul-say-i-am-pure-from-the-blood-of-all-men) I got this comment :

> I've really grown to like how the NLT can help in understanding the
>   original meaning behind a verse. I still like to hold it up against
>   literal translations (as you did) and interlinear bibles, though.

As far as I can understand, the person there says that he really likes NLT version of the Bible, but I am a bit not clear about the latter part of his comment - "I still like to hold it up against literal translations".

Does he like literal translations more than NLT or he still prefers NLT more than literal translations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he meant

"hold it **against**" as in "hold it **next to**" to cross-check both NLT and the other translations.

He likes to refer to both NLT and other versions.

Here against does not mean "opposing" which is what leads to the confusion I think

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me as if he likes to **compare** it with other versions.